# Windows 7 audio service isn't running

Tags: windows-7, audio

Recently I have problems in my audio systems. After startup, there is no sound in my computer. There is a notification in audio service isn't running. Then, I go to services.msc and in windows audio, I click start. I found error, Error 1068: dependency service failed to start.

My Device Model is IntelDH55PJ and my audio driver name is Realtek HD Audio Driver.

My dependency screen shot is given below:

[image: multimedia]

[image: overall]

Comment: please add device model and driver version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Services list double click the audio service and go to the dependencies tab, see what other service it needs to run, then check those service(s) to be sure they are starting when windows loads. When you are in the dependencies tab be sure to expand the services in there to see what they depend on, all these layered services need to be running.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my audio services, there is no dependencies but still audio can not work.

Comment: @Alien Post a screenshot of your dependencies somewhere I can see it please.

Comment: Screen shot is given below @Moab

Comment: Below what?????

Comment: sorry , question is edited and screen shot is given there

Comment: Those are dependencies, everything listed in your screenshot is a dependent service which must be running for the audio service to work.

Comment: Note that, there occurs bluescreen error after installing new ram since then audio driver isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the driver is working:

Get the Computer Management console open (right-click Computer > Manage, or Start > Run > compmgmt.msc) then in the navigation (left-most) pane under System Tools click Device Manager (opens Device Manager in middle pane). Scroll down to and expand the Sound, video and game controllers section, then right-click your audio driver and select Properties. Device status section should read 'This device is working properly'. You may also see an entry under System devices as well.

If the driver(s) aren't working then Google for / download / install the latest specific to your PC's config.

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread when searching for a solution to a problem where **Windows Audio** was failing to start on a Windows 7 guest Virtual Box VM reporting error 1068.

Following the dependencies I found that the **Windows Audio Endpoint Builder Service** failed to start reporting error **1722: RPC server is unavailable**.

The solution that helped me was posted on the [Microsoft Community message board](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/no-audio-cannot-start-windows-audio-endpoint/ed0b46ea-ac67-48cb-bf08-6dd1c7a04d57). It was to start the **Power** service first.

The **Power** service is not listed as a dependency for **Windows Audio Endpoint Builder**, yet when that is started the Audio services also become available.
[image: Windows Audio Endpoint Builder does not list Power service as a dependency (Dialog from a Russian version)]

Answer (score 0):

Following the dependencies I found that the Windows Audio Endpoint Builder Service failed to start reporting error 1722: RPC server is unavailable.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1107017)